# UNIX command find log the last occerrence string that near the specific string

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

Given a log file that contains "print data" that may span multiple lines and then an error, for example:

```
print some data 1
print some data 2
print some data 3
data 3-1
data 3-2
error
print some data 4
print some data 5
```

I want to find any log entries that have an error, for example:

```
print some data 3
data 3-1
data 3-2
error
```

And determine the "print" line that caused the error

what should I do?

Comment: Can you even read and understand what you wrote? If you can't, then surely the rest of us can't...

Comment: `tac file | sed -n '/error/,/print/p' | tac` :)

Comment: @Cyrus not all flavors of UNIX have tac

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk` to do this:

```
awk '$1=="print"{printBuffer=$0} $1=="error"{print printBuffer}' yourfile
```

This splits each record by a space character (awk default). If the first field of the record is "print" it stores the entire record (`$0`) in variable `printBuffer`. If the first field is "error", then it prints whatever is in `printBuffer`, which is the last `print` line that it came across before hitting the error.